# Full width horizontal buttons with jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

In `Jquery mobile`, I can have grouped horizontal buttons, but they the group does not take 100% width.

I tried adding a class that sets `width:100%` but that did not work.

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Update + Possible Fix: It seems that it was failing because I was explicitly using `width="50%"` in both buttons. I did `45%` and the fit. Probably some margins that the buttons have?

Source code with the fix applied: `http://pastebin.com/ZXDNfAU1`

Comment: Added, sorry about that. It 's actually most copy pasted code from the documentation.

Comment: The 'navbar' toolbar is the way to go. There's [another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10929226/how-to-let-jquery-mobile-controlgroup-width-100) discussing this with a code sample.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="submit" data-theme="c">Cancel</button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b">Submit</button></div>
</div>
```

Above will do it if it's not in a footer or header element.  Two column grids are here: 
http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/grids-buttons/

I do not know how to accomplish it within the footer

Answer (score 1):

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
  <a href="index.html" data-role="button">Yes</a>
  <a href="index.html" data-role="button">No</a>
</div>
```

I got code above from the documentation:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1pre/#/demos/1.0b1pre/docs/buttons/buttons-grouped.html

I tried it myself and it works perfectly. You get 2 buttons side by side that expand to fill 100% of the screen.

Comment: doesn't work for me in the latest beta when viewing on iPhone

Comment: how to get full screen width for group buttons

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="ui-grid-solo">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
         <input type="submit" name="Action" value="Register" data-theme="b"/>
    </div>
</div
```

> This works

Answer (score 0):

Inspect it with firebug to see what is causing them to display badly.

And add `data-type="horizontal"` to the controlgroup div in your sources.

Answer (score 0):

If you want horizontal 2 button may be you can use

```
<div style="float:left; " >  
<div style="float:right;" >
```