# how to let jquery mobile controlgroup width 100%?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i'm useing jquery mobile to do a demo...
i want to let the width of localnav be 100%...
but i don't know how to do that...
code here...

```
<ul data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="localnav">
    <li><a href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn-active">111</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">222</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">333</a></li>
</ul>
```

help me pls...thank you...

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [JQuery Mobile's navbar](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html)
Though it's normally used in a header/footer, it can be used elsewhere. It will produce a full-width bar containing your buttons.

```
       <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="plus" data-role="button">Button1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="minus" data-role="button">Button2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-icon="check" data-role="button">Button3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I did.  Worked well.

CSS:

```
<style>
    .ui-grid-a, .ui-grid-a .ui-controlgroup-controls {width: 100%}
    #homePageButton {width:49%;float:left;margin-left:1%}
    #logOutButton {width:49%}
    #footer {height:45px}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" id="footer">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-grid-a">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="home" id="homePageButton">Home Page</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="forward" data-iconpos="right" id="logOutButton">Log Out</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: If you need all your links to have the same width, you can set it (in percentage) with a target like `.ui-controlgroup-controls a` (you'll probably have to give more specificity depending on your markup) and add `box-sizing: border-box` to avoid messing with each element's widths.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are trying to wrap a `<ul>` as a controlgroup. But you can have a full-width ControlGroup with the following approach:

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="localnav">
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn-active">111</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">222</a>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-transition="fade">333</a>
</div>
```

And in CSS, split the width equally among the number of `<a>` elements:

```
a{width:33%;}
```

Sample jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pAuqm/1/

If you want to continue with `<ul>` based structure; you could have full width controlgroup with following CSS:

```
li{
    display: inline;
}
a{width:33%;}
```

Sample jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pAuqm/3/

Comment: Not very elegant, works with wide screens but not pixel perfect.

Comment: @Mad Echet: this works on mobile screens too... And I think its better to use % than PX ... on what device are you seeing this now working?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. It works on all screens but 33% is not 33.3333333% so you cannot guarantee that the right border will be adjusted to the rest of the content (it is a matter of one or two pixels I know). The closer you are to 1/3 the more likely you are to see the last element jump on a new line. I never managed to get it to work at the pixel level to make the design look sleek, I don't understand why they never implemented in jquery mobile. But I'm still looking!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a grid to do this, and one extra css rule:

```
.ui-controlgroup-horizontal > div > .ui-btn {
    width: 99%
}​​​​​​​​​
```

The reason I'm doing this is that the markup like this:

```
<div class="ui-grid-a" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <div class="ui-block-a">
         <button type="submit" data-theme="c">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Is transformed by jquery into markup like this (inspect it in Chrome or Firebug):

```
   <div class="ui-grid-a ui-corner-all 
       ui-controlgroup ui-controlgroup-horizontal" 
       data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
       <div class="ui-block-a">
           <div data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" 
             data-iconshadow="true" data-inline="null" 
             data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="null" data-iconpos="null" 
             data-theme="c" data-mini="false" 
             class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-corner-left" 
             aria-disabled="false">
               <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-corner-left">
                   <span class="ui-btn-text">Cancel</span>
               </span>
               <button type="submit" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn-hidden" aria-disabled="false">Cancel</button>
           </div>
       </div>
       <!-- etc -->
   </div>
```

As you can see, the `.ui-btn` we want to be 100% wide is inside `ui-block-a` (or `ui-block-b`, `ui-block-c`, etc.), and our horizontal control group has gained the class `.ui-controlgroup-horizontal`, hence the rule: `.ui-btn` children of `divs` children of `.ui-controlgroup-horizontal` are made (nearly) 100%. I stop short of 100% because this chops the rounded corners on the right hand button for me. By using `.ui-controlgroup-horizontal` on the top class, and not (say) `ui-grid-a`, this rule works for different grid sizes.